# File auditing with Tasker

Tags: internal-storage, tasker, file-management

Sometimes I find in sdcard files and directories for which I can't guess the app that created them (and I know they are not the default files created by the system). And even if they take up only little space, I would like to delete useless files to keep my phone clean and browse the sdcard more easily. So I want to set up Tasker to do the following:

- constantly perform file auditing,
- when a package is removed ask if I want to remove the files created by that application (this part I know how to achieve).

My question is: **how can I set up Tasker to perform file auditing (if this is possible)?**

Note: I tried some cleaning tools (e.g. Clean Master) that do this, but I want to implement it myself with Tasker, as they are mostly bloatware.

Comment: I've never used any cleaning tool and since you've mentioned that they work in this case, may I know: do they detect any folder created by an app regardless of the name the folder has? // "*when a package is removed ask if I want to remove the files created by that application*" -- ES File Explorer does that but only when the label of folder matches the the label of app. What technique are you using for folders with different labels but created by a single app?

Comment: There is an event named File Modified. Set it to `/` (this is not literal *nix `/` here) to monitor `/sdcard`. To know what has been changed inside sdcard (create/delete/moved), use the task List files after every modifcation and compare the recent output with the earlier output. The anomalies would account for recent modification. However, I can't precisely pin-point which app is responsible for modification in sdcard.

Comment: I'm don't know how cleaning tools do it, it's been a while since I last used them. Probably they rely on the name of the folder and the concurrent creation when a package is installed. Thank you for pointing me to file modified!